# Control does not exist in this current context

Tags: c#

I am in a c# class and i am having to write this code but i dont understand c# that well and I am having this problem with my code. I have 6 Errors in the code they are all the same error saying that

"the name "textbox1MESSAGE" does not exist in this current context"

and if anyone could help me that would be great.
maybe I might learn something as well if someone helps me the teacher does not teach the class. they hand me a book and says read it and understand it and do the class work and take the test. and you will pass the class. I have never had any experience in any computer languages.

here is my code.
 what is wrong with it?
and what did I do wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Do_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int lcv = 1;
        string szmessage = "";

        szmessage += "the Do Loop - ";
        do
        {
            szmessage += lcv.ToString();
            textBox1MESSAGE.Text = szmessage;
            textBox1MESSAGE.Refresh();
            for (decimal i = 0m; i < 1000000m; i++) ;
            lcv++;
        }
        while (lcv < 11);


    }

    private void While_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int lcv = 10;
        string szmessage = "";

        szmessage += "The While Loop - ";

        while (lcv > 0)
        {
            szmessage += lcv.ToString();
            textBox1MESSAGE.Text = szmessage;
            textBox1MESSAGE.Refresh();
            for (decimal i = 0m; i < 1000000; i++) ;
            lcv--;
        }
    }

    private void FOR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int lcv = 1;
        string szMessage = "";

        szMessage += "The For Loop - ";

        for (lcv = 1; lcv < 20; lcv += 2)
        {
            szMessage += lcv.ToString();
            textBox1MESSAGE.Text = szMessage;
            textBox1MESSAGE.Refresh();
            for (Decimal i = 0m; i < 1000000m; i++) ;


             }
          }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Six times there is the line of code with `textBox1MESSAGE` which apparently doesn't exist. So you need to get the real name and there are two simple ways to do this.

1. Go to the Designer view, where you see the form and controls laid out, click on the textbox you're intending to work with and look at the properties of it (can press `F4`).  That is the name you want.
2. Alternatively, you could type, in your code, `this.` and scroll through and see what controls are available for your current form (this).  You don't need the `this.` in front of textboxMessage, it is optional, but this can help you find what you're looking for.

Once you find the correct name of your textbox, you can replace `textBox1MESSAGE` six times with the correct name and there will be no more errors.

If you don't have a textbox yet, you can go to the Designer and from the Toolbox you can drag and drop a textbox, and name it textBox1MESSAGE, or whatever you'd like.

Comment: Thank You it was a very simple mistake. I cant believe I couldn't think of it.

Answer (score 4):

That means that the name of the textbox on your form is not `textBox1MESSAGE`.  In the designer, you can click on the textbox and then look at the properties window to find it's ID.

Also, you don't need to call `Refresh` on the textbox.  When you set the value of `Text` it will display the change automatically.